# Moving Log in or Register Link to Top Links in Header Navigation - Magento

Tags: php, css, magento

Hope I got the Title correct.

I've bought a theme from Themeforest -- http://www.newsmartwave.net/vigoshop/index.php/?___store=demo2_default

Basically on the top you have Home, Account, Shopping & Checkout in the top links. I have removed all except Account Link in the Top links using the Local.XML. Below the top links you have ‘Log in or Register’ Link. When you use this link to Login, the Link changes to Logout so the customer can log out. But what I want to do is replace the Account Link in the Top Links to the ‘Log in or Register’ so then I can remove the option below. for example see this screen grab https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKMol.png.

I don't know how I can do this, please can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
    <?php
        $loggedIn = $this->helper("customer")->isLoggedIn();
        if($loggedIn == 1){
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout/',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())); ?>" class="sign-link pull-left"><?php echo $this->__('Logout') ?></a>
    <?php
        }else {
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())); ?>" class="sign-link pull-left"><?php echo $this->__('Log In or Register'); ?></a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>    



**Local.xml**
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log in or Register</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><liParams/><aParams>class="top-link-account"</aParams></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for the bought theme files for `class="sign-link pull-left"`

Once you have found it from source then you can delete it.

Comment: Deleting is not the issue, I want to move it to the top in the top links navigation, instead of having it below. it just looks daft.

Comment: In this case copy whatever you have in the location where is class top-links, next to the other menu items there and add same classes.

Comment: This is what I've found in the Class section, put the code inside the top question. And also pasted the Local.xml section too. So don't know how I'd move the whole coding to the Local.xml.